# How to pass arguments from wrapper shell script to Java application?

Tags: java, scripting, executable

I want to run Java programs I am creating at on the command line (linux and mac).  I don't want to type "java" and arguments all the time, so I am thinking about creating wrapper scripts.  What's the best way to do this so that they work everywhere?  I want to be able to pass arguments, too.  I was thinking of using "shift" to do this (removing first argument).

Is there a better way to do this without using scripts at all?  Perhaps make an executable that doesn't require invocation through the "java" command?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a shell that is compatible with the Bourne shell; e.g. sh, bash, ksh, etc, the following wrapper will pass all command line arguments to the java command:

```
#!/bin/sh
OPTS=... 
java $OPTS com.example.YourApp "$@"
```

The `$@` expands to the remaining arguments for the shell script, and putting quotes around it causes the arguments to be individually quoted, so that the following will pass a single argument to Java:

```
$ wrapper "/home/person/Stupid Directory Name/foo.txt"
```

Without the double quotes around `"$@"` in the wrapper script, Java would receive three arguments for the above.

---

Note that this does not work with `"$*"`.  According to the `bash` manual entry:

> *`"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1c$2c..."`, where `c`
>                 is the first character of the value of the `IFS` variable.*

In other words, all shell arguments would be concatenated into a single command argument for your Java application, ignoring the original word boundaries.

Refer to the `bash` or `sh` manual ... or the POSIX shell spec ... for more information on how the shell handles quoting.

Answer (score 6):

You can [create a shell script](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_create_a_shell_script_on_a_macintosh.html) that [accepts arguments](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SHL_automate/_Passing_to_shell_script.html). In your shell script, it will look something like this:-

```
java YourApp $1 $2
```

In this case, `YourApp` accepts two arguments. If your shell script is called `app.sh`, you can execute it like this:-

```
./app.sh FirstArgument SecondArgument
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will break if the wrapper script is called with quoted arguments; e.g. pathnames containing spaces.  It needs double quotes around `$1`, `$2` etcetera