# Taking a program from dos shell and run in java

Tags: java

How to take a program that runs on a dos shell and send the text that comes from the shell program into a java program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments from wrapper shell script to Java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771755/how-to-pass-arguments-from-wrapper-shell-script-to-java-application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program)